# Webots: robot simulator

Tags: webots

I downloaded and try various versions of the Webot software but after installing it always shows the error of unexpected stop working webots on windows. I need the software please give some solution.

Comment: Could you add the exact error message and/or a screenshot?

Comment: What is exactly the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to make sure to update the driver of your GPU.

You might also try to start Webots using the safe mode: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/starting-webots#safe-mode